# "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" when I add a class from setTimeout

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, settimeout

the following code gives me a **Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation**:

```
document.querySelector("h1").addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  setTimeout(this.classList.add, 2000, "bold-h1");
});
```

But what's wrong with it? Wouldn't that be the same as if I would write

```
document.querySelector("h1").addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  setTimeout(() => { this.classList.add("bold-h1"); }, 2000);
});
```

? (the latter works by the way)

Comment: Related: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions invoked by *setTimeout* are executed as global code. The *add* method is expected to be called on a *classList* object (i.e. its *this* will be a *classList* object), but in the case of global code its *this* will be the global object or undefined in strict mode.

The global object doesn't have a *classList* property so *this.classList* returns *null*, and calling any method (or even attempting to access any property) of *null* throws an error.

The reason that the second case works is that the function passed as the listener wraps the arrow function. An arrow function's *this* is bound to the *this* of its enclosing execution context, so the arrow function's *this* is the *this* of the listener, which is the element the listener is on. So now when the anonymous function is called by *setTimeout*, its *this* is the element and `this.classList.add(...)` works.